# Pandas map according to values in multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

I want to use a mapping that maps a unique value to a DataFrame based on corresponding values for 2 or more series
For example if c is the mapping that uses values of columns 'a' and 'b' as shown

[image: map]

then for the dataframe below I should have the mappings as:

[image: df]

Like for each (0, 0) pair in the dataframe shown above the value of c is 1, (1,1) pair will have a value 4, etc.

The logic should extend to multiple columns, i.e. there can be columns C1,C2,C3 and for the combined unique value of each of these I should be able to map a value to the dataframe containing these values.

Also the order of rows of the 2nd dataframe must not change

What will be the most elegant way to do this? Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the second input? You're mapping from a DataFrame which just has columns a and b?

Comment: Yes, the dataframe has only columns a and b, and c is the unique value corresponding to values of a and b. Although I can have more than 2 columns and the logic should be able to map unique values for them too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2.merge(df1, how="left")
```

See also the [merging section of the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).

Comment: But the order of rows of df2 is changing, which should not happen